# IE to Edge Migration

Tags: internet-explorer, migration, microsoft-edge

I have an application that supports and runs only on IE mode and now I need the application to support and run on native Microsoft edge as well. What are the compatibility/migration steps I need to follow technically to make the application support and run on Edge browser?

The suggestion from internet is full of configuration changes in the browser and local settings.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing I suppose is you'll need to know whether you have any deprecated/unsupported API in your application that is supported in IE but not in Edge. Also, please note that ActiveX controls and BHO are not supported in Edge. Edge is designed to work with current web standards like HTML 5.